# How to exclude specific files in Sonar?

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, teamcity

I am using SonarQube on a C# .Net application via TeamCity. This application has jQuery in a folder with a bunch of other scripts. I would like to exclude a number of JQuery files from analysis but have Sonar analyze all the other files in the folder. One such JQuery file is at the following path:

```
...MyProject\Content\Scripts\jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js
```

I have added the following line to the additional parameters section of the SonarQube Runner build step:

```
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/Content/Scripts/jquery*
```

in an effort to exclude all files that start with jquery in that folder however the file is not being excluded from the analysis. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

I locally created an example project, containing a java file and a file called `Content\Scripts\jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js`.

---

`~/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner` led to these logs:

```
...
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
...
INFO: Sensor JavaScript Squid Sensor [javascript]
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
...
```

and the javascript file was visible in SonarQube.

---

`~/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.exclusions=**/Content/Scripts/jquery*` led to these logs:

```
...
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   **/Content/Scripts/jquery*
INFO: 2 files indexed
INFO: 1 file ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
...
```

and the javascript file was successfully excluded (not visible in SonarQube).

---

**Conclusion**

Your mentioned configuration should work. My guess is, that the analysis report cannot be processed for another reason and you are seeing old data in SonarQube.

Please verify your sonar runner logs and the status of your background tasks in the SonarQube administration pages.